# In the context of derivatives pricing, what are Pillars and Marking?

Tags: pricing, volatility-smile

as the title says, I've heard of the terms 'Pillar' and 'Marking' in the context of fitting volatility smiles and derivatives pricing in general and I'm having difficulties finding definitions on Google. I would be very grateful if someone could clear this up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillars tend to refer to maturities/expiries in the fixed income world. Marking - is basically where your official system has the value of a particular benchmark security at a particular point in time (eg end of day for example).

Comment: I'll add that those benchmark securities are also usually used to compute the 'mark' of a possibly more complex, or non benchmark security (via some assumptions or model) so at the end of everyday you have a PV of your whole book

Comment: thanks, very helpful! So marking is just used to check how well your model fits by comparing to realized prices/IVs, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Well it's used to calc pnls. Computer risks. Ofcourse as you say you also don't want to be mismarked by much either. It also enables you to price new business with adjustments to get to the mkt price ofcourse

Comment: So I suppose if we had market prices of some type of option, with which we calculate the greeks, implied volatility etc. If we then used those in our model to calculate the price then that use of the real world model parameters is marking, correct ?

Comment: My 0.02 USD: usually there are many sources of prices (Reuters, Bloomberg, the exchange, expert opinion, etc. which might diverge or be =@NA). Marking is the decision made by you/your organization that as far as you are concerned the price of ABC security on date T is X and no other. Mis-marking (which if intentional could be a serious regulatory violation) is when you assign a price which is not objectively justified.

Comment: Well the prices you're saving or using to infer those parameters is technically what you're marking to. Parameters etc all have their own assumptions, models, noise. The idea is that your model, if well calibrated should be able to reprice the prices that go in (I.e. the marks). Agree with @nbbo2 there too.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot both of you !